# Медленная работа DTW при распознавании слов

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, распознавание-речи

Написал небольшую программу распознавания отдельных слов при помощи DTW.

В папке с программой лежит еще одна папка `Data20dict`, в которой вложены еще 20 папок с названиями голосовых команд (`вставить`, `копировать`, `удалить` и т.д.), в каждой из которых, в среднем, по 21 произношению (от 17 до 25 произношений в папке). Одно произношение - один звуковой файл в формате `*.wav`. Всего получается 437 произношений всех слов, записанных в формате `*.wav`.

Для алгоритма DTW пользуюсь модулем [(DTW)](https://github.com/pierre-rouanet/dtw) (Dynamic Time Warping Python Module).

Ниже представлен код программы:

```
from numpy.linalg import norm
from dtw import dtw
import os
import timeit
import librosa
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


DATA_PATH = './Data20dict/'
SAMPLE_RATE = 16000

train = dict()
test = dict()

#Читает все звуковые файлы из всех директорий
#и создает словарь из слов и их произношений
for path in sorted(os.listdir(DATA_PATH)):
    full_path = os.path.join(DATA_PATH, path)
    if os.path.isdir(full_path):
        class_name = path.upper()
        class_files = [os.path.join(full_path, f) for f in sorted(os.listdir(full_path))]
        waves = [librosa.load(file, sr=SAMPLE_RATE)[0] for file in class_files]
        train_waves, test_waves = train_test_split(waves, test_size=0.2)
        train[class_name] = train_waves
        test[class_name] = test_waves

train_mfccs = dict()
test_mfccs = dict()

#Все произношения раскладываются на mfcc матрицы
for class_name in train:
    mfccs = []
    for sound in train[class_name]:
        mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y = sound, sr = SAMPLE_RATE, hop_length = 512, n_mfcc = 13)
        mfccs.append(mfcc)
    train_mfccs[class_name] = mfccs

    mfccs = []
    for sound in test[class_name]:
        mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y = sound, sr = SAMPLE_RATE, hop_length = 512, n_mfcc = 13)
        mfccs.append(mfcc)
    test_mfccs[class_name] = mfccs

#Каждое произношение из тестовой выборки сравнивается
#со всеми произношениями из обучающей выборки   
correct_hmm = 0
correct_dtw = 0
total = 0
a = timeit.default_timer() 
for key_test, val_test in test_mfccs.items():
    for test_words in val_test:
        total += 1
        max_dist = [float("inf")]
        for key_train, val_train in train_mfccs.items():
            for train_words in val_train:
                dist, _, _, _ = dtw(test_words.T, train_words.T, dist=lambda x, y: norm(x - y, ord=1))
                if dist < max_dist:
                    max_dist = dist
                    output_label_dtw = key_train
        if key_test == output_label_dtw:
            correct_dtw += 1

dtw_time = timeit.default_timer() - a
print('\nКоличество слов в тестовой выборке: {}'.format(total))
print('\nDTW: Верно распознано {} из {} тестовых слов'.format(correct_dtw, total))
percent_correct_dtw = round((correct_dtw/total * 100.0),2)
print('\nDTW: Процент распознавания: ', percent_correct_dtw)
print('\nDTW: Затраченное время на распознавание: ', dtw_time, 'секунд')
```

В итоге результаты работы примерно следующие:

**1 вариант:**
Количество слов в тестовой выборке: 34
DTW: Верно распознано 31 из 34 тестовых слов
DTW: Процент распознавания:  91.18
DTW: Затраченное время на распознавание:  37.73047312543349 секунд

**2 вариант:**
 
Количество слов в тестовой выборке: 97
DTW: Верно распознано 96 из 97 тестовых слов
DTW: Процент распознавания:  98.97
DTW: Затраченное время на распознавание:  384.3671420063365 секунд

Если есть у кого-то идеи, что может тормозить работу, или кто знает как улучшить алгоритм (может добавить ближайших соседей или как-нибудь еще), поделитесь знаниями.

Comment: В общем решил проблему. В дополнение к функции dtw еще импортирую fastdtw, и вместо строчки с расчетом норм вставляю следующую строку: dist, _, _, _ = fastdtw(test_words.T, train_words.T, 'euclidean'). В итоге с 384 секунд программа выполняется за 49 секунд, что уже вполне неплохо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем как подсказали, помогло профилирование, там понял в чем была проблема. Она заключалась в расчете лямбд (евклидова расстояния) в функции dtw(). В общем вместо него импортируем fastdtw и меняем:
`dist, _, _, _ = dtw(mfcctest.T, mfcctrain.T, dist=lambda x, y: norm(x - y, ord=1)`)
На:

```
dist, _, _, _ = fastdtw(test_words, train_words.T, 'euclidean')
```

Расчет стал производиться почти в 8 раз быстрее. Это помогло.